# Why is this an empty space appearing inside of SVG element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk4xbn4w/) with this problem. If I set viewBox property on the **symbol** element, icon displayed correctly. But if I set viewBox with same value on **svg** element with **use** inside, around **use** element appears weird empty space, inside of SVG-container.

Viewport of first variant is the same with viewport of second variant - 35x35px size at 2.5x3.5px coords.

What's the reason of this behavior? Bug or my own mistake?

**EDIT:** Add picture with correct and incorrect areas.
[image: Empty space inside SVG]

```css
#svg-icons {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.icon + .icon {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="icon-1" viewBox="2.5 3.5 35 35">
    <rect x="2.5" y="3.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="35" height="35" />
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="20" cy="21" r="14" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="icon-2">
    <rect x="2.5" y="3.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="35" height="35" />
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="20" cy="21" r="14" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon-1" width="100" height="100">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-1"></use>
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon-2" viewBox="2.5 3.5 35 35" width="100">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-2"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: @amphetamachine added screenshot with examples of correct (when viewBox on the symbol element in svg-sprite) and incorrect icons (when viewBox on the svg element outside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probrem will be solved by thinking about how the use element is treated on drawing.
According to [SVG 1.1 2nd edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement), use element refers symbol element is treated as svg element on drawing. So the result by that svg structure is same as this.

```
<svg class="icon icon-2" viewBox="2.5 3.5 35 35" width="100">
    <g>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%">
            <rect x="2.5" y="3.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="35" height="35" />
            <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="20" cy="21" r="14" />
        </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Inner svg element has range of 100% width and height positioned at (0,0), and outer svg element has viewBox offset to (2.5, 3.5). 
Thus shapes are cutoff by displacement of 2 svg element's rendering ranges.